# Android vertical scrolling doesn't work

Tags: android, vertical-scrolling

A TextView field is supposed to scroll vertically.  It doesn't.  Why not?
Also tried attaching a vertical scrollbar -- it pops up briefly, then disappears, and still no scrolling.
A real pain for a large String text message in the box.

Comment: We cannot help much without seeing some code :-)

Comment: Hmmm, I am guessing it is because you coded it improperly?  Seriously though, you'll have to post some code or be much much more specific in your question for anyone to be able to help.